# Android Tablets networked via server locally and access video files

Tags: java, android

I have a project where in i have to network android based tablets to a server locally without internet connection.
Scenario:-

there is a classroom where all 50 students have tablets now i want to stream videos from server directly to tablets (instead of downloading it to various tablets individually). this tablets can be connected via lan to server locally but internet is not available.

Thanks in advance
Himesh